# How to put map in PagerAdapter? Is it possible?

Tags: android, dictionary, android-viewpager

Now i can create PagerIndicator but i don't know how to put map it, which one page will show Driving Stat. and another one will show map+driving stat. In addition, Is it possible to make 2 view work together as you see in the picture below.(the time and distance still run)

[image: UIsample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about GMap control but here is how I use different layouts in my app.
First you could create a layout for your Map control
Secondly add it in your ViewPager

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) SettingsActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0: //first page
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourMapLayout,
                null);
        TextView text = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("I am an added text")
...
```

If I understood corect and you are using **android.support.v4.view.ViewPager** , which would be a good candidate to accomplish your task.

Comment: I try some... it force close and show this in logcat 01-26 17:37:23.382: E/AndroidRuntime(570): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity. /// then, i go to fix mainActivity to extend MapActivity... lucky, app able to run but, it doesn't show map.. just empty page with TitlePageIndicator

Answer (score 1):

I use below code and it works :)

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem( View pager, final int position )
        {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = null;

            if(position == 0) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_map, null);  
                ((ViewPager) pager).addView(view,0);   
            }
            return  view;
    }
```